# my program loop in the do while

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying t learn Java and trying to do small program but i have a little problem with this one cause i am stuck in the do while loop when i choose the answer "N"
can you please help me out

```
package calculatrice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calculatrice fonction =new Calculatrice();
    Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean noury= true;
    boolean Sonia= true;
    String expression = sr.nextLine();

    while(noury)
    {
        if(expression.contains("+"))
        {

            float x = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\+")[0]);
            float y = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\+")[1]);
            float c = fonction.somme(x, y);
            System.out.println("le resultat " + c);

        }

    if(expression.contains("-"))
        {

            float x = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\-")[0]);
            float y = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\-")[1]);
            float c = fonction.soustraction(x, y);
            System.out.println("le resultat " + c);

        }

    if(expression.contains("*"))
        {

            float x = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\*")[0]);
            float y = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\*")[1]);
            float c = fonction.multiplication(x, y);
            System.out.println("le resultat " + c);

        }

    if(expression.contains("/")){

        float x = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\/")[0]);
        float y = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\/")[1]);
        float c = fonction.divion(x, y);
        System.out.println("le resultat " + c);

    }


    do{
        System.out.println("voulez vous effecteur une autre operation");
        System.out.println("O pour Oui ");
        System.out.println("N pour Non ");
        String choix = sr.nextLine();

        if ((!(choix.equals("O")))&& (!(choix.equals("N"))))
        {
            Sonia =false;
            System.out.println("La valeur saisit n'est pas Correcte veulliez choisir N ou O seulement");
         }
        else if(choix.equals("N"))
           {
            noury=false;
            }
        else
                {
            System.out.println("Entrez une nouvelle valeur à calculer");

                }
        }while(Sonia);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: The loop continues until `Sonia` is false, which only happens if you enter something *other* than `O` or `N`. Try `X`.

Comment: What's the point of the inner loop? If it's to keep asking until you get "O" or "N", that's the exact opposite of what you're doing.

Comment: Side note: all those nested parentheses are unnecessary. This will work just as well: `if (!choix.equals("O") && !choix.equals("N"))`

Comment: By the way, once `Sonia` is set to false, it will never be true again.

Comment: Hello shmosel thank you for your quick answer i will try what you ask and try to set Sonia and my loop better

Comment: thank you Andreas i didn't reazlly understand what you  want to say but to explain here is the behavior that i want it to happen.    the introduce an expression then we ask the user if he would like to run an other commande if it O it mean yes so we let him run an other commande if it N it end the program it its niether N nor O it should ask him to in put again his choise that should be just O or N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any French, but it seems like `noury` indicates that the outer loop should continue while `Sonia` indicates that the inner loop should continue. The outer loop performs the main logic while the inner loop is strictly to get user input, so it seems - correct me if I'm wrong. It appears that if the input is neither "N" nor "O", you want to ask for input again. In the block of code under the "if" condition, you should leave `Sonia` as true, so that the inner loop runs again. If the input is "N", it appears you intend the program to end. Setting `Sonia = false;` in the block beneath your `else if` condition will end the inner loop, and the `noury = false;` already present will cause the outer loop to end. Under the else block, when the user inputs "O" to indicate that they want to run another command, set `Sonia` to false so the inner loop ends. Finally, set `Sonia = true;` before your inner loop. I believe that these steps will provide the behavior you want.

Comment: Hello Daniel thank you for your quick answer   yes you're right so I ask him if he would like to do an other action and like you said the outer loop (the while loop with noury) and this intend the program to end if the user input "N" but if he does input "O" he can input and new expression to calculate. but if it's neither "N" nor "O" it will ask him to input again and that is happening in the do while loop. I will try what you said and ket you know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the value evaluated for the condition (while or do/while) in the loop. 
In your second loop, you evaluate the value `Sonia` of but change the value of `noury`.

tip: use meaningful variable names, it helps to avoid such errors. And some [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) do exists for example for variables (avoid `Sonia`, it looks like the name of a class).

Answer (score 0):

So I made it work with all your help 
first of all i had to put in the first loop the `String expression =sr.nextLine();`
then i did what in the seconde loop sonia to false here is my changes

```
`package calculatrice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {



 public static void main(String[] args) {

 Calculatrice fonction =new Calculatrice();
 Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
 boolean cond1= true;
 boolean cond2= true;


 while(cond1)
 {
   String expression = sr.nextLine();
  if(expression.contains("+"))
  {

   float x = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\+")[0]);
   float y = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\+")[1]);
   float c = fonction.somme(x, y);
   System.out.println("le resultat " + c);

     }

 if(expression.contains("-"))
  {

   float x = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\-")[0]);
   float y = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\-")[1]);
   float c = fonction.soustraction(x, y);
   System.out.println("le resultat " + c);

  }

 if(expression.contains("*"))
  {

   float x = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\*")[0]);
   float y = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\*")[1]);
   float c = fonction.multiplication(x, y);
   System.out.println("le resultat " + c);

  }

 if(expression.contains("/")){

  float x = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\/")[0]);
  float y = Float.parseFloat(expression.split("\\/")[1]);
  float c = fonction.divion(x, y);
  System.out.println("le resultat " + c);

 }


 do{
  System.out.println("voulez vous effecteur une autre operation");
  System.out.println("O pour Oui ");
  System.out.println("N pour Non ");
  String choix = sr.nextLine();

  if ((!(choix.equals("O")))&& (!(choix.equals("N"))))
  {
   cond2 =false;
   System.out.println("La valeur saisit n'est pas Correcte veulliez choisir N ou O seulement");
   }
  else if(choix.equals("N"))
     {
   cond1=false;
   }
  else
    {
   System.out.println("Entrez une nouvelle valeur à calculer");
      cond2 = false;
    }
  }while(cond2);
 }

 }

}`
```